# Error while cloning Windows VM which has GPU via Windows Admin Center Server Manager

Tags: windows, powershell, gpu, virtual-machine, servermanager

I am trying to clone an existing GPU windows VM to another one using Windows Admin Center Server Manager.  Clone has finished good,  meanwhile I am unable to start and use both vms at the same time.  Individually both works good.  While trying to start the second one, I am getting the below error.

> RemoteException: Failed to start virtual machine Revit2. Error:
> 'Revit2' failed to start. Virtual Pci Express Port (Instance ID
> E7F4F120-206F-4EB2-8538-85468C8BBE74): Failed to Power on with Error
> 'The device is in use by an active process and cannot be
> disconnected.'. 'Revit2' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID
> F3755FE1-6BF6-49DF-8AE6-B6B86DE02696) 'Revit2' Virtual Pci Express
> Port (Instance ID E7F4F120-206F-4EB2-8538-85468C8BBE74): Failed to
> Power on with Error 'The device is in use by an active process and
> cannot be disconnected.' (0x80070964). (Virtual machine ID
> F3755FE1-6BF6-49DF-8AE6-B6B86DE02696) Could not allocate the PCI
> Express device with the Plug and Play Device Instance path
> 'PCIP\VEN_10DE&DEV_2482&SUBSYS_88121043&REV_A1\4&1D81E16&0&0019'
> because it is already in use by another VM.

The main HyperVM windows Node is having two GPU "Asus TUF 3070Ti 8GB",  The master of the clone is already using one.  What I understand is both vms are trying to use the same grafic card hence the error.  How can I solve the issue?  The master HyperVM node is only having WINDOWS CLI.